# How to add number in collection laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, counter, laravel-5.6

If I `dd($items)`, the result like this :

[image]

I want to add number to each array

So the first array, exist key number with value 1

The second array, exist key number with value 2

etc

I try like this :

```
$items->map(function ($item) {
    $item['number'] = 1;
    return $item;
});
```

Number does not increase. I'm confused to make the counter

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try it like this

```
$newItems = $items->map(function ($item, $index) {
    $item['number'] =  $index + 1;
    return $item;
});
```

**Edit:** Based on comment (I don't recommend it because then you can not get benefit of eloquent model. It simply return you an array )

```
$newItems = $items->map(function ($item, $index) {
    $number = ['number' =>  $index + 1];
    return $number + $item->toArray();
});
```

Comment: It works. But I want the key number position to be first. Not the last

Comment: Can you update your answer with `prepend`? So I can receive your answer

Comment: is your item a eloquent Model ? If is your collection of model object then i will suggest you to use it as it is . If not then you can convert your object to array and just use '+'

Comment: Yes, my item is a eloquent model. What do you mean? You better update your answers with scripts and some options. So I understand easily

Comment: It does not work. There exist error like this : `Object of class App\Models\Item could not be converted to int`

Comment: my mistake, updated answer, should be  `$item->toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $counter=1;
 $items->map(function ($item) use(&$counter){
   $item['number'] = $counter++;
   return $item;
});
```

Comment: It works. But I want the key number position to be first. Not the last

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge

```
$newItems = $items->map(function ($item, $index) {

  return array_merge(array("number" =>  $index + 1), $item);;
});
```